# Android: Notify when user reads SMS

Tags: android, notifications, sms

Is there a way to notify through the intent service when the user opens an SMS conversation?

I was just trying to browse through the list of 
android.intent.action.*

but couldnt find anything that matches this.

Any help, please?

Comment: Do you mean locally? Or are you trying to track SMS messages which you have sent? The latter is not possible, and the former can't be done through intents directly, the closest I can think of would be to register your application to receive SMS with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />` and `<data android:scheme="sms" />` and handle the tracking of when those received messages have been viewed separately.

Comment: @FerretallicA - Please can you tell me how it can be handled separately? All I wanted is that to enable a possibility of recording the message in sdcard. So, the user will open a message and click on a button..

Comment: Declare an SMS intent with the action `android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"` and use `android:priority` to ensure your app gets to process incoming messages before anything else does. Your app can record the message however it wants and, as long as it doesn't cancel the incoming SMS broadcast, the SMS will be handled normally once your app is finished logging it to the SD card (or to wherever, doesn't matter really)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FerretallicA. How about to handle the message if its viewed or not? I mean, how will we know which message is currently being viewed?